# CSS spaces, top element or bottom element?

Tags: css

Whenever I format a website according to a PSD file, 
I always wonder if the space should be from the top element or the bottom one.

So if I have 2 elements that are seperated by some space, I normally choose 
the top one, but I can't find a real reason not to choose the one on the bottom.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a simple code example that shows the two elements you're trying to lay out? It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking at present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would typically add it to the upper element as `padding-bottom:10px` (or whatever whitespace size you need.

I find that I typically want "any content after this" to be a certain distance away.  very rarely do I find the reverse ideal. (although its an easy modification if needed)

Comment: Be also aware of [margin-collapsing](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins), which allows to add the space to both elements.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the same two elements as siblings (for example, a header div followed by a menu div at the top of each page), then there is no difference between adding margin-bottom (or padding) to the top vs. adding margin-top to the bottom.

OTOH, if the elements in question sometimes appear elsewhere in the document (for example, an H2 can be an article title followed by a byline in one place or a subheading followed by a paragraph elsewhere), then the answer will depend on how you need them to behave in each of the places.